# My android app gets killed when in background on nexus 6p

Tags: android, nexus-6p

I had a problem running my app on Nexus 6p: My Android app is getting killed every time my app is moving to background.

I have already set this app to be 'Not Optimized' and made reboot - but still had no success. I see that my Activity's onDestroy() is called for every time..

Any idea?

Comment: if it crashes show logcat , and also show the code where the crash happens

Comment: Is it working fine on other phones?

Comment: Please share if you've got any exceptions. It'll be helpful to find out the issue.

Comment: Do your Nexus 6P have Android O? If yes then you have to Read some articles regarding Android O

Comment: currently It crashes since the app assumes the activity is not destroyed - I can handle it but I do not want to restart my activity each time app goes to bg. the app is properly running on other HUAWEI p9 and more devices (this is the only one I have problems with) . I'm trying to figure out why the activity is being destroyed on this device.

Comment: It is just normal behavior, Android may shut down apps when it needs the resources (memory for example). Your App must be able to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any way or reason to run app in background. [This](https://developer.android.com/training/best-background.html) link shows how to run tasks in background. If your use case doesn't fit in scenarios described there, please provide it in problem.